# SwiftyJSON Item At Index Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

I have the following dummy JSON data:

```
{
 "folder": {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "Home",
     "parent_folder_id": null,
     "num_of_items": 10,
     "num_of_items_complete": 10,
     "children": {
         "folders": [
               {
                   "id": 2,
                   "name": "Identification",
                   "num_of_items": 4,
                   "num_complete": 4
               },
               {
                   "id": 3,
                   "name": "House and Household Equipment",
                   "num_of_items": 6,
                   "num_complete": 2
               },
               {
                   "id": 4,
                   "name": "Insurance",
                   "num_of_items": 4,
                   "num_complete": 3
               },
               {
                   "id": 5,
                   "name": "Owned Items",
                   "num_of_items": 6,
                   "num_complete": 5
               }
        ],
         "input_fields": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "key": "Something",
                "value": "Dark Side",
                "type": "text"
            }
        ],
        "shortcuts": [

        ]
     }
  }
}
```

And I need to access each child in "children" with an INDEX rather than by it's NAME for a collectionView:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.data["folder"]["children"][section].count
    }
```

But it always returns 0 for the count. Is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: There is `folders` under `children` dict so `self.data["folder"]["children"][section]` should crash.

Comment: The value for key `children` is clearly a dictionary (see the curly braces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
return self.data["folder"]["children"]["folders"].count
```

I think is the only way you can do it.